# ZAP automatically returning same response on breakpoint

Tags: testing, proxy, breakpoints, owasp, zap

I'm using OWASP ZAP as a proxy tool for testing mobile applications.
What I'm trying to do is make a breakpoint on some URL, and return custom response to test applications UI or functionality.

Currently, whenever breakpoint is triggered, I have to manually let request pass, and then change the response and let that one pass in order to see the change in the app. And when I have to do it multiple times, it's not really convenient. 
Is it possible to make a breakpoint on a URL that will return some predefined response every time it is triggered?

If it's not possible, are you aware of any other tool that is?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that, but not with breakpoints - they are manual only.
Instead you can either use either :

- [Replacer](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/wiki/HelpAddonsReplacerReplacer)
- [Scripts](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpAddonsScriptsScripts)

The replacer is easier to set up but more restricted while scripts can do absolutely anything. There are example scripts for replacing scripts in response headers and bodies.

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for. Replacer works like a charm but with certain limitations, as you said. Im going to try the scripts as well, it is a bit more complex indeed. Not sure why it's not letting me accept the answer. Also, small note, replacer link is wrong, it leads to 'Alert Filters' instead of 'Replacer'.

Comment: ha, yeah - fixed the link now :)